# What is the significance of the tangent to a curve that passes through the origin?

Tags: calculus, geometry, economics, slope

Why the tangent shows the value of Max Average Product Labor(APL)? Besides why the secant of APL and Marginal Product Labor represent the tangent of the Total Product curve passing through the origin?
Ref: SCHAUMS OUTLINE Series Microeconomics Book by Dr.Dominick Savatore (Chapter: Theory of Production)
[Figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xI2yT.png)

[Data Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BbFz0.png)

Comment: Please edit your question to give more context, say what all the acronyms mean, where did this data/figure come from. Also try rephrasing your question because, to me at least, it doesn't make any sense at the moment.

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience. Please check it now.

Comment: You should @ them

Comment: The graphs shows just the APL and MPL. What exactly is your question?